# Select specific column from sqlite query as specific array?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a query similar to this:

```
c.execute('''select FileSize, FileName, FileType from ExampleTable
    where FileType = ?''', [FileType])
bestCRThLocal = list(c.fetchall())
print(bestCRThLocal[0]);
```

I want to have arrays for FileName, FileType and FileSize each own their own.

What is best way to do this in python?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip). Example:

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]
>>> zip(*l)
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```